# Godot - set_offset works in Inspector but does not work in code

Tags: godot

If I set offset using the Inspector, the enemies will spawn from the correct offset but will not do so when setting the offset via the code below. Also...

```
print(spawn_point.get_offset())
```

...displays 1000 as would expect but enemies spawn from (0,0)

Ideas?

```
extends Node

func generate_enemy(index):
    var enemy = get_node("enemies").get_child(index).duplicate()
    for child in get_node("common").get_children():
        enemy.add_child(child.duplicate())

    randomize()

    var spawn_point = get_node("SpawnPath/SpawnLocation")#.set_offset(1000)#randi() % 2000) # <<< remove 2000 after testing

    spawn_point.set_offset(1000)

    print(spawn_point.get_offset())
    print(spawn_point.get_h_offset())

    enemy.set_pos(spawn_point.get_pos())

    enemy.reference_bullet = enemy.get_node("reference_bullet").duplicate()
    enemy.remove_child(enemy.get_node("reference_bullet"))
    return enemy
```

Comment: What kind of object is `spawn_point`?

Comment: Like @rcorre said, it would be very useful if you add types to your code snippet, otherwise it's hard to analyze.

Comment: spawn_point is a pathfollow2d

Comment: Are you using Godot v2? If not, are there any errors printing in the console?

Comment: Did you make sure to add a Curve2D to your Path2D? If not, offset will be updated but the PathFollow2D will not move.

Comment: @hola, yes, godot 2.

Comment: @hola, no, just the pathfollow2d

Comment: I know that if your `Path2D`'s `curve` does not have any points your `PathFollow2D`'s offset can be set, but it will not move. I setup a scene and could not reproduce issue where setting `Offset` in the inspector works but not from code. Could you post a minimal project demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this video?  https://youtu.be/vZ62xv_C520

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had deleted the Curve2D from the Path2D and even though I drew a new Curve, it didn't save for some reason. If the Curve property on your Path2D node doesn't have an undo icon, it's probably the same reason. Just close the scene and open it again.